# Bundler / eventmachine install issue (Rails / Windows 8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, eventmachine

I am trying to install the gem EventMachine on Windows 8 (using Ruby 1.9.3 with RubyInstaller) via bundle, but I get the following error. None of the previous solutions posted here worked for me.  I greatly appreciate any help in advance

```
   C:\Sites\routes_controller_exercise>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using multi_json (1.3.6)
Using activesupport (3.2.6)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.6)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.3)
Using actionpack (3.2.6)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.6)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
Using activerecord (3.2.6)
Using activeresource (3.2.6)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.7.3)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.15.3)
Using railties (3.2.6)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using daemons (1.1.8)
Installing eventmachine (0.12.10)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... no
creating Makefile

make
generating rubyeventmachine-i386-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is val
id for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is v
alid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:26:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:85:0: warning: "FD_SETSIZE" redefined
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling cmain.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is val
id for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is v
alid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from cmain.cpp:20:0:
project.h:26:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning
In file included from cmain.cpp:20:0:
project.h:85:0: warning: "FD_SETSIZE" redefined
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:98:71: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:109:122: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:119:79: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:129:83: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:260:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:270:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:280:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:290:51: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:300:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:320:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:546:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:669:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int,
 const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: 'fstati64' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmach
ine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.


C:\Sites\routes_controller_exercise>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'eventmachine', '~> 1.0.0.beta.4.1'
```

and run bundle install again, if you have some error about that you're requesting for another eventmachine version and there is a bundle currently gem of eventmachine, you can remove the "Gemfile.lock" and run bundle install again (although it's not good to do, but it worked for me)

PD: I hope this solution works for you too.

Comment: I couldn't increase eventmachine version on the Gemfile since it got pulled transitively by another package, however I can get it to install the latest version by deleting the old Gemfile.lock (it seems old version of this got checked into version control) and rerunning `bundle install`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Confirming above answer works.

First I forced it to download the newest eventmachine using the following command:

```
gem install eventmachine --pre
```

I added the following line to my gemfile:

```
gem 'eventmachine', '1.0.0', :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]
```

Then found and edited my gemfile.lock with the following lines:

```
rake (10.1.0) #
## eventmachine (1.0.0)
eventmachine (1.0.0-x86-mingw32)
```

Then reran bundle install, and all was well. Hope this helps you!